# How Send data Between two Activities

Tags: android

i m working on Application there i have two activities with Edit-text boxes .In 1st Activity  i have check box when the user click check box he will redirect to 2nd Activity  there again Some fields to be filled. after filling that fields and clicking the submit button will submit the data of 2nd activity to 1st activity through Share preference but on 1st activity i lose all the filled data from my edittext  boxes So how can i save previous activity data

**My 1st Activity  Code**

```
enter code here

CheckBox foodyes;
Button submitB;

EditText foodrate;

EditText rate;
EditText tax;
EditText amount;
TextView total;
EditText persons;
EditText advannce;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

    mDisplayDate =findViewById(R.id.tvdate);

    foodyes =findViewById(R.id.foodyesbox);
    submitB=findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
    foodrate=findViewById(R.id.foodrate);

    rate =findViewById(R.id.ratetext);
    tax =findViewById(R.id.taxtext);

    amount=findViewById(R.id.amounttext);

    total=findViewById(R.id.totaltext);
    persons=findViewById(R.id.persontext);
    advannce=findViewById(R.id.advancetext);

    foodrate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Amount"));

    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
            int year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day =cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog =new DatePickerDialog(
                    Booking.this,
                    R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    year,month,day
            );
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY));
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    mDateSetListener =new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

            month=month + 1;
            Log.d(TAG,"onDateSeT: mm/dd.yy" + month+"/" +day+"/"+year);

            String date = month + "/" +day +"/"+year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);



        }
    };

    foodyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent foodyes = new Intent(Booking.this,foodyesbox.class);
            startActivityForResult(foodyes,1);
        }
    });



    **My 2nd Activity Code**
```

public class foodyesbox extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button foodbtn;

private EditText quan1;
private EditText price1;
private EditText quan2;
private EditText price2;
private EditText quan3;
private EditText price3;
private EditText quan4;
private EditText price4;
private EditText quan5;
private EditText price5;
private EditText quan6;
private EditText price6;
private EditText quan7;
private EditText price7;
private EditText quan8;
private EditText price8;

private TextView totalfood;
private EditText amountbox;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foodyesbox);


    foodbtn=findViewById(R.id.foodsubmitbutton);

    quan1=findViewById(R.id.quan1);
    price1=findViewById(R.id.price1);
    quan2=findViewById(R.id.quan2);
    price2=findViewById(R.id.price2);
    quan3=findViewById(R.id.quan3);
    price3=findViewById(R.id.price3);
    quan4=findViewById(R.id.quan4);
    price4=findViewById(R.id.price4);
    quan5=findViewById(R.id.quan5);
    price5=findViewById(R.id.price5);
    quan6=findViewById(R.id.quan6);
    price6=findViewById(R.id.price6);
    quan7=findViewById(R.id.quan7);
    price7=findViewById(R.id.price7);
    quan8=findViewById(R.id.quan8);
    price8=findViewById(R.id.price8);

    totalfood=findViewById(R.id.totalfoodtext);
    amountbox=findViewById(R.id.amountfoodtext);

    totalfood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            if(quan1.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan1.setText("0");
            }

            if(price1.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price1.setText("0");
            }


            if(quan2.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan2.setText("0");
            }

            if(price2.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price2.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan3.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan3.setText("0");
            }

            if(price3.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price3.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan4.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan4.setText("0");
            }

            if(price4.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price4.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan5.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan5.setText("0");
            }

            if(price5.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price5.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan6.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan6.setText("0");
            }

            if(price6.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price6.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan7.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan7.setText("0");
            }

            if(price7.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price7.setText("0");
            }

            if(quan8.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                quan8.setText("0");
            }

            if(price8.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                price8.setText("0");
            }



            int quant1=Integer.parseInt( quan1.getText().toString());
            int prize1=Integer.parseInt( price1.getText().toString());
            int quant2=Integer.parseInt( quan2.getText().toString());
            int prize2=Integer.parseInt( price2.getText().toString());
            int quant3=Integer.parseInt( quan3.getText().toString());
            int prize3=Integer.parseInt( price3.getText().toString());
            int quant4=Integer.parseInt( quan4.getText().toString());
            int prize4=Integer.parseInt( price4.getText().toString());
            int quant5=Integer.parseInt( quan5.getText().toString());
            int prize5=Integer.parseInt( price5.getText().toString());
            int quant6=Integer.parseInt( quan6.getText().toString());
            int prize6=Integer.parseInt( price6.getText().toString());
            int quant7=Integer.parseInt( quan7.getText().toString());
            int prize7=Integer.parseInt( price7.getText().toString());
            int quant8=Integer.parseInt( quan8.getText().toString());
            int prize8=Integer.parseInt( price8.getText().toString());
            int mult=(quant1*prize1) +(quant2*prize2) +(quant3*prize3) +(quant4*prize4)+ (quant5*prize5) +(quant6*prize6) +(quant7*prize7)+(quant8*prize8);


            amountbox.setText(String.valueOf(mult));



        }
    });

    foodbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String amount= amountbox.getText().toString();
            Intent foodbtn=new Intent(foodyesbox.this,Booking.class);
            foodbtn.putExtra("Amount",amount);
            startActivityForResult(foodbtn,1);



        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in second activity update

```
foodbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String amount= amountbox.getText().toString();
            Intent foodbtn=new Intent(foodyesbox.this,Booking.class);
            foodbtn.putExtra("Amount",amount);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, 1)
        }
    });
```

And in first activity add

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // You get result from second activity
            String text = data.getExtras().getString("Amount");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you think that my answer for the initial problem helped you, please consider Upvote answer to make is useful to others too. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 1st Activity:

```
String string="Your Text";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);    
i.putExtra("name",string);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the new Activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
```